# Curl Post with php failing on localhost always

Tags: php, curl, localhost, wamp

I'm running Apache with php on my local machine using wamp. Imade sure the dll files are uncommented in php.ini (under apache and php bin folders). I have the below function that whenever I invoke I get the error:

Curl failed with error 7 Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused

The function is:

```
function post($data) {
    try{
    $postUrl = "127.0.0.1:8000";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$postUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $x = curl_exec($ch);

    if (FALSE === $x)
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

    curl_close($ch);

} catch (Exception $e){
    $x = 'Curl failed with error ' . $e->getCode().' '.$e->getMessage();
}
return $x;
}
```

I have researched all through SOF for this but to no avail.

Comment: Is anything Listening on port 8000?

Comment: I enabled this port and added it to my httpd.conf file on wamp. But no , it looks like the port is not listening. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is in `$postUrl`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably specifying the wrong port. The default port that Apache listens to is port 80 (and this is also true for wampserver's implementation of Apache if I remember correctly). Try this:

```
function post($data) {
    try {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '127.0.0.1:80');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($response === false) throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

        curl_close($ch);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $response = 'Curl failed with error ' . $e->getCode() . ' ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: No that's not the case, I want to use a different port so that I can listen to these posts using sockets.

Comment: Also, if I use port 80, for some reason, I am being redirected to the localhost main page, although I'm using an echo statement when I invoke my function. Nothing is being posted